# EclipseLink does insert command in wrong tenant

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I'm using tenant by schema and i have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA)
public class Person {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CTPS ctps;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CTPS")
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA)
public class CTPS {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_CTPS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CTPS_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID"))
    private Person person;
}
```

During an update at the same time using two differents tenants, occurs key violation error in one of requests, because tenant_a is trying to execute an insert in person_ctps table using tenant_b.

I'm using:
postgresql-9.4.5-3
wildfly-8.2.0
EclispeLink 2.6.3 with patchs of issues 410870 and 493235.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide ore information on the details leading up to this situation.  Are you reading from one tenant an persisting to another for instance?

Comment: Two thread persisting at the same time, each one in your respective tenant separated by database schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The object that maintain relation tables is not cloned in EclipseLink.

With the attachment patch of issue [498891](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498891), the problem is solved